# jQuery object array from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have a few inputs with data attribute and value. I want to get data attribute for key and for value to get value from input. And where the value repeats it to be recorded only once.

Here is my demo https://jsfiddle.net/7L3eugqp/.

The result that I want should be look like that:

```
"A_1_1": {1, 2, 3},
"A_1_2": {4, 5, 6}
```

I will be grateful if someone give me advice how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. A link to a fiddle is useful, but not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You were overriding the first dataset each time your loop found another element.

```
var datasets = {};
$('.project').each(function(index, value) {
    catName = $(this).data("prefix");
    datasets[catName] = datasets[catName] || {
      label : catName,
      data: []
    };
    datasets[catName].data.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(datasets);
```

If you don't want to have `1` twice (treat them as distinct sets), you can enclose the `push` call in this if statement:

```
if (datasets[catName].data.indexOf($(this).val()) === -1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use 2 loop. the first to create datasets and the second to push data :

```
$('.project').each(function(index, value) {
    catName = $(this).data("prefix");
    if(!$.contains(datasets,catName)){
        datasets[catName] = {
        label : catName,
        data: []
      };
    }
});

$('.project').each(function(index, value) {
    catName = $(this).data("prefix");
    datasets[catName].data.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(datasets);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y6c5gw7o/